# Handle redirect when the uri is not listed on location in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-location

I am  new nginx and I am trying to setup a wildcard based redirect to an external domain [domain1.com to domain2.com] based on couple of conditions.

If the location /path is not mentioned in the list of redirects then the redirect must go to domain2.com/landing-page.

But if the user types domain1.com/about-us which is listed in redirect, then it needs to take to domain2.com/about-us. Is there a way to check out the location redirect list and then do a redirect to the relevant page.

```
location / {
 rewrite ^/$ https://domain2.com/landing-page permanent;
 rewrite ^/about-us https://domain2.com/about-us permanent;
 rewrite ^/contact-us https://domain2.com/contact-us permanent;
}
```

Thanks in advance